# Load multiple values into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I made this Webpage where you can click on a picture and it gives you some code into a textarea which you can copy. So far so good ... but I only managed to make it possible that everytime you click one of those pictures that it replaces the current code in the textarea, not add it. The target is to put your own layout together and copy the code at the end, not every little piece of code for itself.

```
 <body>
    <a class="gridstyle grid-70-30" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/70-30.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="gridstyle grid-30-70" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/30-70.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="gridstyle grid-33-33-33" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/33-33-33.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="gridstyle grid-25-25-25-25" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/25-25-25-25.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="gridstyle kategorien" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/kategorien.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="textausgabe"></div>

    <button class="copy">Copy Textarea</button>
    <textarea id="target"></textarea>
</body>



<script id="grid-70-30" type="text/template">
    <div class='grid12-8'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='clearer'>
</script>

<script id="grid-30-70" type="text/template">
    <div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-8'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='clearer'>
</script>    

<script id="grid-33-33-33" type="text/template">
    <div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='clearer'>
</script>   

<script id="grid-25-25-25-25" type="text/template">
    <div class='grid12-3'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-3'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-3'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-3'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='clearer'></div>
</script>   

<script id="kategorien" type="text/template">
    <div></div>
</script> 




    <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery("button.copy").click(function () {
            jQuery("textarea#target")[0].select();
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            if(successful) {
                alert('Copied');
            }

        });



        jQuery(".grid-70-30").click(function () {
            jQuery("textarea#target").val( jQuery.trim(jQuery("#grid-70-30").html()));
        });

        jQuery(".grid-30-70").click(function () {
            jQuery("textarea#target").val( jQuery.trim(jQuery("#grid-30-70").html()));
        });

        jQuery(".grid-33-33-33").click(function () {
            jQuery("textarea#target").val( jQuery.trim(jQuery("#grid-33-33-33").html()));
        });

        jQuery(".grid-25-25-25-25").click(function () {
            jQuery("textarea#target").val( jQuery.trim(jQuery("#grid-25-25-25-25").html()));
        });

        jQuery(".kategorien").click(function () {
            jQuery("textarea#target").val( jQuery.trim(jQuery("#kategorien").html()));
        });

    </script>
```

Do you guys have any idea how to do that? Cause I don't!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example. I've refactored your code, to keep it simple.

I've changed your `anchor` tags by moving `grid-*` names from classes to `data-grid` attribute.

```
class="gridstyle" data-grid="grid-70-30"
```

This way we can simply get grid type you clicked by referencing it from `data-grid`.

```
var grid = $(this).attr('data-grid');
```

After that we just add a new value to existing one.

Run `Run code snippet` to see it in action.

```js
$('.gridstyle').click(function(e) {
  var grid = $(this).attr('data-grid');
  var textarea = $('#target');
  
  var oldValue = textarea.val();
  var newValue = $('#' + grid).html();

  textarea.val(oldValue + newValue);
});
```

```css
textarea {
height: 100px; width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button class="copy">Copy Textarea</button>
    <textarea id="target"></textarea>


    <a class="gridstyle" data-grid="grid-70-30" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/70-30.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="gridstyle" data-grid="grid-30-70" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/30-70.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="gridstyle" data-grid="grid-33-33-33" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/33-33-33.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="gridstyle" data-grid="grid-25-25-25-25" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/25-25-25-25.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="gridstyle" data-grid="kategorien" href="#"><img src="http://www.awesome-business.com/hero/kategorien.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="textausgabe"></div>




<script id="grid-70-30" type="text/template">
    <div class='grid12-8'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='clearer'>
</script>

<script id="grid-30-70" type="text/template">
    <div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-8'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='clearer'>
</script>    

<script id="grid-33-33-33" type="text/template">
    <div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-4'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='clearer'>
</script>   

<script id="grid-25-25-25-25" type="text/template">
    <div class='grid12-3'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-3'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-3'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='grid12-3'>Hier steht Inhalt</div><div class='clearer'></div>
</script>   

<script id="kategorien" type="text/template">
    <div></div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read the current value of the textarea into a variable, add (concatenate) the html to it, then assign it back to the textarea.

And you can simplify your javascript code like this:

```
jQuery('.gridstyle').on('click', function(event){    
  var gridClass = this.className.substr(10),
      selectedGridHtml = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#' + gridClass).html()) + "\n",
      txtArea = jQuery('#target');

  txtArea.val(txtArea.val() + selectedGridHtml);
});
```

I'd also suggest to use a data attribute to identify the `gridClass`, like `data-grid` that way you can read it with `this.dataset.grid`